# Is there a place in the registry that allows for the deletion of people apps in win 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I logged into face book, manually unfriended all my friends, then deleted my face book account, but when I started the people app, all my previous contacts were still there, isn't there a place in the registry that will allow for the deletion of the people app contacts, surely there must be. Please help.

Thanks, Matt

Comment: What version of Windows?  If you are using Windows 8 then I don't believe Modern UI applications can even access the registry.  It doesn't sound like deleted your Facebook account if you were able to log into the account.

Comment: he uses Windows 8. Look into the title (people app in Win8)